# Fetch status 200 but pending endllessly, except first call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, promise, fetch-api

I've been searching to solve this problem for a while but couldn't find a working solution.

I'm making a simple social network website and this API returns a article data such as text, image and video URL, etc, all saved in server's local MySQL Database. My front-end is React and server is Nginx reverse proxy with Node.js using Express. When I load the page, I create 5 React components that each make fetch request for given article number.

The following code snippet is the fetch API that asks the server to fetch data from database:

```
//server-side script
app.get('/api/getArticle/:id', (req, res) => {
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'myhost_name',
        user: 'myUser',
        password: 'myPassword',
        database: 'myDB',
    });
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("Connected!");
    })
    const idInterest = req.params.id.toString();
    console.log(idInterest)
    let sql = 'some_sql';
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Error while getting article data");
            return;
        }
        else {
            res.set('Connection', 'close')
            res.status(200).send(result);
            console.log("ended")
            con.end();
            return;
        }
    })
}
//React script
//index.js
fetch('http://mywebsite.com/api/getMaxArticleId/')//Retrieve top 5 article ID
.then((response) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        nodesList.push(<Container articleId={data[i]['id']}/>)
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><NavBar />{nodesList}<Writer writer="tempWriter" /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root'));
})
//Container.jsx; componentDidMount
const url = "http://mywebsite.com/api/getArticle/" + this.props.articleId.toString();
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: "include",
    }).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            //processing json data
```

This used to work very fine, but suddenly the `getArticle/:id` calls started to show 200 status but 'pending' in 'time' column in Chrome network tab, endlessly, **all except the first***`getArticle/:id`**call**. This prevents my subsequent `.then()` in each `Container` from being called and thus my entire tab is frozen.

[Link to image of network tab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vHiCJ5Q_Ga1N-kj9ltsCPZKP1HJvydS7/view?usp=sharing)

As you see from the image, all pending fetches are missing 'Content Download' and stuck in 'Waiting(TTFB)', except the first call, which was '39'

I checked the API is working fine, both on Postman and Chrome, the server sends result from DB query as expected, and first call's Json response is intact. I also see that `console.log(response.json())` in React front-end shows `Promise{<pending>}` with `*[[PromiseStatus]]: "Resolved"*` and `*[[PromiseValue]]*` of `Array(1)` which has expected JSON data inside.

[See Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rrxCSx9_owqjmDD-dFGbPexpZwRuzSr7/view?usp=sharing)

This became problematic after I added YouTube upload functionality with Google Cloud Platform API into my server-side script, so that looks little suspicious, but I have no certain clue. I'm also guessing maybe this could be problem of my React code, probably index.js, but I have no idea which specific part got me so wrong.

I've been working on this for a few days, and maybe I need common intelligence to solve this (or I made a silly mistake XD). So, any advice id welcome :)

Comment: I suggest you to put `console.log` in couple of places, ex. inside `Container`, so that you do see number of calls made, matches with number of record from your first List call.  You are supposed to see Lots of calls, instead of one call to fetch everything. So if one of your call is pending, that just means all your calls should be pending. Btw your first call isn't same as your rest of calls, the first one is for Listing.

Comment: @windmaomao Oh sorry, my explanation was confusing. When I meant first 5 calls, I meant 5 getArticle/:id calls from each ```Container```, excluding the very first ```getMaxArticleId``` call from index.js. The ```getMaxArticleId``` was successful.  Anyways, thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: Then it is your server side issue, maybe you shouldn't call `con.end()`. Try to put a single statement inside server, so to see if you can make five success call first, the `con.query` isn't important for the debugging purpose.

Comment: What is `con`? Where do you create it (and more importantly, where do you open the db connection)?  What mysql library do you use? Is `sql` really a global variable?

Comment: @windmaomao I tried with ```res.status(200).end()``` and ```pending``` doesn't seem to appear now. I know the API works fine, then I'm guessing it's problem of playing with JSON in client-side, but I'm clueless where I'm missing out. Does failing to correctly handle response even affect ```pending``` status of following requests...?

Comment: @Bergi ```con``` is node.js mysql connection object. I declared both ```sql``` and ```con``` and established connection first in app.get method for user validation purpose but it was trimmed out while I was making code simpler. I've included it in question.

Comment: I'm puzzled at ```Promise{<pending>}``` that has ```[[PromiseStatus]]: "Resolved"```. Is this promise resolved or pending...?